# Bit Manipulation in Java - Conditionally Toggling Bits Based on Bit Values?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I have 8 Objects we will call "lights". Each light can be toggled on or off (0 or 1). Each light has an index (0-7).

I have no familiarity with Bitwise operations in Java, but I think the following code checks whether the light is on or off properly:

```
int value = 128;
int index = light.getIndex();
boolean lightIsOn = (value >> (index & 0x1) == 1);
```

I am currently facing the problem of not being able to turn on all of the lights. For example, if light 0 is on and I turn on light 1, light 1 will say it is on, but light 0 will then say it is off. That is with the following code:

```
if (!lightIsOn) {
   value = (value | 1 << index);
}
```

I know I am setting it improperly. I just can't figure out how to. This stuff doesn't exactly compute in my brain. I've read up on all of the Bitwise operators and it still doesn't really make sense to me. Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably, `(value >> (index & 0x1) == 1)` ought to be `((value >> index) & 0x1) == 1`.

Comment: Yes!! thank you so much @kaya3 ! I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: Why not just use boolean variables?

Comment: I believe the answers here will be helpful to future readers, as they provide strategies for debugging bitwise operations. Thus, this question does not meet the criteria for closure, "resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to "turning on the light" is okay.

You might think it is broken because there is a bug in how you test whether a "light" is on. Let's break it down:

```
boolean lightIsOn = (value >> (index & 0x1) == 1);
```

Starting with the innermost parentheses, you intersect `index` with 1. This results in shifting `value` one bit if the index is odd, and doing nothing if the index is even.

Then you compare the result of the shift with 1.

If `value` is 3 and `index` is zero, you get an erroneous `false` result. If `value` is greater than three, you get `false` regardless of `index`, which may be erroneous.

An expression like this will give intended results:

```
boolean lightIsOn = ((value >>> index) & 1) == 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down like this, it provided me with an actual understanding of why the expression was wrong. I can say I learned something today! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I generally use debugging for this sort of thing. While it's great to just sort it out in one's head, sometimes it's nice to see the actual bitset. I commented out the intermediate debug statements, after I saw that it was working correctly:

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
  int value = 128;

  public static void main(String[] args){
    StackOverflowTest test = new StackOverflowTest();
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(test.value));
    System.out.println("is 7 on? " + test.lightIsOn(7));

    System.out.println("\n-- turnOff(7) --");
    test.turnOff(7);
    System.out.println("is 7 on? " + test.lightIsOn(7));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(test.value));    

    System.out.println("\n-- turnOn(4) --");
    test.turnOn(4);
    System.out.println("is 4 on? " + test.lightIsOn(4));
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(test.value));
  }

  boolean lightIsOn(int index) {
//    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
//    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(index & 0x1));
//    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value >> index));
//    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((value >> index) & 0x1));
//    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
//    return value >> (index & 0x1) == 1; // this is not working
    return ((value >> index) & 0x1) == 1;
  }

  void turnOff(int index) {
    if (lightIsOn(index)) {
//      System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
//      System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1 << index));
//      System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
      value = (value ^ (1 << index));
    }
  }

  void turnOn(int index) {
    if (!lightIsOn(index)) {
//      System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
//      System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1 << index));
//      System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(value));
      value = (value | (1 << index));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your approach of debugging step-by-step and will adopt it for future complications. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it may help you.

If your light number is less than 32.

You could try to use bit computing for each light. For example:

```
light1: 1
light2: 2
light3: 4
light4: 8
light5: 16
light6: 32
light7: 64
light8: 128

So If the mumber is 2: that will be light2
So If the mumber is 3: that will be light1 and light2
So If the mumber is 15: that will be light1,light2,light3,light4
```